# Does a Google Play developer account cost more than $25 with tax?

Tags: google-play, account, google-developers-console, developer-console, google-console-developer

Does a Google play developers account cost more than $25 with tax? Or is there no tax when buying an account?
The reason I ask is I'm going to buy a Visa gift card so my friend can purchase an account and I wanted to just get the $25 one.
Sorry if this is not the right forum for this post.

I live in USA if that change things.

Answer (score 2):

If it at all works the same way that google domains works, I think that you end up paying no tax. It might very state by state. To be safe, you really should consider buying a $30 gift card. From my experience you should be ok with $25.

Comment: It only cost me $25 flat. I never needed to buy G Suite account to make apps. My question is, is there tax when you buy a Google Play developer account?

Comment: @MattVine My bad I will update this to reflect that. I was signed into my school email which affected how I was seeing the page.